# error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'node_t*'

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Whenever I try running the code below, I get the following error on line 34:

> error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'node_t*'

I'm new to pointers and linked lists, and I was watching a tutorial on how to use them (this one: [Understanding and implementing a Linked List in C and Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VOpjAHCee7c)), and I copied the most of it exactly like shown in the video, but it still doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
   int value;
   struct node *next;
} node_t;

void printlist(node_t *head){
    node_t *temporary = head;
    while(temporary != NULL){
        cout << temporary -> value << endl;
        temporary = temporary -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
node_t *create_new_node(int value){
    node_t *result = malloc(sizeof(node_t));   // <----- line 34
    result->value = value;
    result->next = NULL;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    node_t *head;
    node_t *tmp;
    tmp = create_new_node(32);
    head = tmp;
    tmp = create_new_node(8);
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    tmp = create_new_node(34);
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    printlist(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. what is line 34? 2. Changing `printf`'s to `cout`'s does not mean, you changed it to C++.

Comment: It wasn't just that, it had other little things.
And line 34 is `node_t *result = malloc(sizeof(node_t));`
Just count.

Comment: `Just count` ??? - seriously?

Comment: I mean is one to do it. I'm new to this sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace *malloc* with *new*

Perhaps read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/malloc-vs-new/

Note the line

```
    node_t *result = new node_t;
```

in the below code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
   int value;
   struct node *next;
} node_t;

void printlist(node_t *head){
    node_t *temporary = head;
    while(temporary != NULL){
        cout << temporary -> value << endl;
        temporary = temporary -> next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
node_t *create_new_node(int value){
    node_t *result = new node_t;
    result->value = value;
    result->next = NULL;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    node_t *head;
    node_t *tmp;
    tmp = create_new_node(32);
    head = tmp;
    tmp = create_new_node(8);
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    tmp = create_new_node(34);
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    printlist(head);
    
    return 0;
}
```

A running version at godbolt

https://godbolt.org/z/7PvohY4b5

Comment: Note that I have supplied you a fully running version including the ``#include`` and ``using`` statements you have left out. In the future when submitting C++ questions you will be less likely voted down if you ensure that you include everything that when pasted into godbolt will demonstrate your issue. Even better supply a link to an existing godbolt example.

Comment: Thanks that worked and I'll sure be using it from now on.

Comment: And thanks for the feedback, I've updated the post with the #include and using statements

Comment: I would also recommend not writing ``using namespace std`` rather ``std::cout`` everywhere. It's generally frowned upon to import the *std* namespace. It works but you might run into problems later on if you get into this habit. Other people will pick you up on this sometimes if you post code like that.

Comment: Memory leak: https://godbolt.org/z/zzd1MMbv4

Comment: Sure. There are three allocations with new and no deletes. This is not surprising but the question was narrowly focussed. I see you have written a more detailed tutorial on using smart pointers. Fine but I suspect that OP is not at that level of understanding with C++ yet. However your point about using smart pointers is valid +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have copied `C` exampele of List and tried to convert it to C++.

This line:

```cpp
node_t *result = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Is valid in C, since in C implicit conversion from `void*` to other types of pointer is allowed. Note that `malloc` return type is `void*`.

In C++ type `void*` is treated more restrictively and such implicit conversion has been dropped.

One way to fix it is replace `malloc` with operator `new` as other answer suggests (will not replicate it).

Other way is to apply conversion `node_t *result = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));`, but this is not nice and language purist can complain about UB.

It would be best if you learn more modern C++ and use `std::unique_ptr`. Something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct node {
   int value;
   std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};

void printlist(node *head)
{
    auto *p = head;
    while(p != NULL){
        cout << p->value << '\n';
        p = p->next.get();
    }
    cout << '\n';
}

std::unique_ptr<node> create_new_node(int value){
    return std::unique_ptr<node>{new node{value}};
}

void list_insert(std::unique_ptr<node>& head, int value)
{
    auto tmp = create_new_node(value);
    tmp->next = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(tmp);
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<node> head;

    list_insert(head, 32);
    list_insert(head, 8);
    list_insert(head, 34);

    printlist(head.get());
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bWbva44fa

Comment: Consider using std::make_unique ( since c++14 ) to get rid of the function create_new_node.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but aggregate initialization do not cooperate with it. I would had to add explicit constructor. Basically there are tree ways to approaches for this: current way, make_unique and add constructor with initializes `value` or make_unique and initialize value in separate line (then return).